# How to fix scrollview/grid layout from applying left and right margin values at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, for some reason unity is deciding to add left and right margin values on my "Content" game object at runtime.

I'm using grid layout, and everything is set to expand.

While in play mode, I can select the "content" game object and alt + stretch on the transform and it aligns back correctly.

**My hierarchy :**

[image]

**Content GameObject Before Runtime:**

[image]

**Content Gameobject After Runtime:**

[image]

**Result in game:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, what I found out seems to be a weird bug, I think. If I don't "check" Horizontal on the scroll view it bugs out. Even though I'm not using the scroll view in a horizontal fashion, I have to check it and it aligns properly again.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's what fixed it? I would have thought it was the `ContentSizeFitter` you've got - it looks like your option was previously set at `Unconstrained`. I would have thought you'd need it set to `Preferred Size` like the vertical setting.

Comment: @Chuck I'm positive, If I get time, I'll record a video showing you the difference unchecked and checked without changing any other parameters. I'm a little confused though, Both pictures up above on the content size fitter shows the same settings.

Comment: yeah the two shots are the editor and runtime values, but both shots show that, for your RectTransfotm, "Some values driven by ContentSizeFitter." If your content is populated dynamically at runtime then it might look correct without content and then get hosed at runtime when the content is added. Pure speculation on my part though.